# What is the meaning of "punch" in technical terminology?

Tags: meaning, technical

What is the meaning of "punch" in technical terminology?

The original phrase is from the "Autocar Road Test 1967" article about Moskvich de Luxe.

> An inexpensive, sturdy, well-equipped car, lacking in punch and refinement.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you googled the word? The meaning is a fairly normal definition of the word.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 

Yes, I did, but the Internet definition only covers the meaning of hole punching.

Comment: [Check out this definition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/punch). It's the 1.2 under the noun form of the word.

Comment: OALD: *[punch: (uncountable) the power to interest people](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/punch_2)*

Comment: @Hank - to a NNS "a car lacking in punch" may sound difficult to understand. This question should probably be moved to ELL.

Comment: @Josh I agree, but I see no evidence that the OP ever found that definition. If they had posted that they had found multiple definitions but needed clarification which one fit, I'd understand a bit more.

Comment: @Hank - ok, but just a little help wouldn't harm anybody, especially a new NNS.

Comment: @Josh I'm all for helping, which is why I posted a link to the definition she needed. I merely just wanted to know what research had been done, since that is a requirement for all posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Punch** means excitement. Commonly, *packing a punch* or *lacking a punch*.

[American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language (5th Edition):](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/punch)

> 1. A **blow** with the fist.
> 2. Impressive or effective **force**; **impact**.

The quote says the car is solid but boring.

Comment: It's usually a good idea not to answer questions that can be answered by [commonly-available references](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573), like a simple dictionary result.

Comment: @Hank - Thank you for the politeness, since we are not in agreement. I felt I was adding to knowledge of the nuances of our language, while you may feel I am rewarding empty questions.

Comment: I see no reason to be impolite :) Everyone has differing opinions on this sort of thing.

Comment: You will see that the question has been put on hold for lack of reasonable reaearch. Providing 'answers' for such easily answered (let-me-google-that-for-you) questions invites other such inappropriate (for ELU) questions. As @Reg Dwight has said, '[W]e write stuff in comments that is too obvious to qualify for an answer. [This] is not really a topic for a site for linguists and etymologists, and we don't want it to become a topic.'